# Sending Sms in background through AsyncTask is not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, smsmanager

On click of a button I want to send sms to numbers got from database in background. If I call the `SmsManager` directly on click it works. But through `AsyncTask` it is not working. Please help me out. Here is my code ..

```
public class SendSmsActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    Spinner level;
    EditText textSMS;


    private ArrayList studentInfo = new ArrayList();

    private DatabaseHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private String levelSelected,sms;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_sms);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        level = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersms);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
        String levelSelected = level.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String levelSelected = level.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
                //getphonenum(levelSelected, sms);

                new MySmsTask().execute(levelSelected, sms);



            }
        });
    }

    private void getphonenum(String levelSelected, String sms){

        mHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Phone FROM student where level= '" + levelSelected + "'", null);
        studentInfo.clear();

        if (mCursor.moveToLast()) {
            do {

                String phoneNumber = (mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.Phone)));
                Log.d("DEBUG", phoneNumber);



                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, sms, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            while (mCursor.moveToPrevious());
        }


    }

    private class MySmsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Senescent "  + params, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            getphonenum(levelSelected, sms);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent "  + " messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}


    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, you declare vairable levelSelected and sms 3 times... ,that is the cause, in your AsyncTask the two variable are null

Comment: `String levelSelected` -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: check ans may this help u

Answer (score 0):

**u can not directly use Toast in doInBackground
use handler to show the toast message may that's why problem arise.**

**please check your method  getphonenum(levelSelected, sms) is called or not**

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override 
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {       
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Senescent " + params, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });
    getphonenum(levelSelected, sms);
    return null;

}
```